# How to print Count, Sum of backbone collections items using underscore.js and

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, grouping

I have following

```
 var cart= [{ item: "A", price: 2 },
             { item: "B", price: 3 },
             { item: "A", price: 2 },
             { item: "C", price: 5 },
             { item: "C", price: 5 },
             { item: "A", price: 2 }];
```

Now i wanted output like.

```
Item   Price   Qty   Total
A      2       3     6    
B      3       1     3
C      5       2     10
```

Answer (score 1):

For a given `item`:

```
var sub = myCollection.where({item: item}),
    length = sub.length,
    total = _.reduce(sub, function(memo, num){ return memo + num; }, 0);
```

If you want to do it for all your items but they can take an unlimited number of values, I would recommend to sort your collection first, then just loop over the found values.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `_.reduce` to build the object that you need

```
var reduced = _.reduce(cart, function(merged, object, index){ 
    merged[object.item] = merged[object.item] || {};
    merged[object.item] = {
        item: object.item,
        price: object.price,
        qty: (merged[object.item].qty || 0) + 1,
        total: (merged[object.item].total || 0) + object.price
    }
    return merged;
}, {});
```

This will give you the following and it can be used to build the table

```
{
    "A": {
        "item": "A",
        "price": 2,
        "qty": 3,
        "total": 6
    },
    "B": {
        "item": "B",
        "price": 3,
        "qty": 1,
        "total": 3
    },
    "C": {
        "item": "C",
        "price": 5,
        "qty": 2,
        "total": 10
    }
}
```

It is not necessary to use `_.reduce` function. You can achieve the same result using any mapping function or `each` loop. Please modify this code if you need an array as the final result.

Answer (score 0):

I have done using following

```
var groups = _.groupBy(cartCollection, function(model){
                return model.get('item');
            });
            _.each(groups,function(group){
                console.log('Item: ' + group[0].get("item") + ', Price: ' + group[0].get("price") + ', Qty: ' + group.length + ', Total: ' + (group[0].get("price") * group.length));
            });
```

Now output would be

[image]